# How to filter objects based on the Symfony workflow's place which is an array?

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I've been struggling with this for a while but can't find a clean way to do it, so I'm seeking for some help.

I have custom filters (ApiPlatform 2.5 and Symfony 5.1) on database API outputs, and I need to filter on the current workflow place, or status as you like, of each output.

The Status has the below structure, which is a symfony workflow's place :

`Status = { "OPEN": 1 }`

My issue is that the status is stored as an array in the DB, and I can't find a way to have the querybuilder finding a match.

I've tried to build locally an array to do an = , a LIKE or an IN :

```
$status['OPEN'] = 1;

$queryBuilder->andWhere(sprintf('%s.Status = :st', $rootAlias))
   ->leftJoin(sprintf('%s.Objs', $rootAlias), 'o')
   ->andWhere('o.Profile = :p')
   ->setParameters(array(
        'st' => $status,
        'p' => $profile
));
```

But no way :(

I implemented a workaround that works but I don't like it as I'm using workflows a lot and need a clean way to filter outputs.
My workaround is fairly simple, when the status is writen as an array in the DB, I also store it as a string in another field called StatusText, then filtering on StatusText is easy and straight.

Status can have different contents obviously : OPEN, CLOSING, CLOSED, ...

Help appreciated !!
Thanks

**EDIT & Solution**

As proposed by Youssef, use scienta/doctrine-json-functions and use JSON_EXTRACT :

composer require scienta/doctrine-json-functions

**Important**, that was part of my issue, use the Doctrine type **json_array** an not array to store the status or the state, however you call it, in the Database.

Integrate the alias provided inside the ApiPlatform custom filter :

```
$rootAlias = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];

$json_extract_string = "JSON_EXTRACT(".$rootAlias.".Status, '$.OPEN') = 1";

$queryBuilder->andwhere($json_extract_string )
->leftJoin(sprintf('%s.Objs', $rootAlias), 'o')
->andWhere('o.Profile = :p')
->setParameter('p', $profile);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to ask Doctrine if the JSON array contains the status, but you can't do that with the QueryBuilder method.
When you hit the ORM limitations you can use a Native Query with ResultSetMapping. It allows you to write a pure SQL query using specific features of your DBMS but still get entity objects.
Or you can use **scienta/doctrine-json-functions** and use *JSON_EXTRACT*

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried the package but face an error : 3141 Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_extract . Argument 1 is the Status array from the DB which is literal in the DB : a:1:{s:4:"OPEN";i:1;}  so it might be that the parser rejects it as a non JSON no ?

Comment: ok, that was the issue, I changed the ORM var type to json_array instead of array and it works. I'll edit my post to help others if someone struggles like I did ...